# Are there any types of tests I can add to my existing solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, testing

I have looked into TDD, unfortunately the project has had most of the development completed, and there isn't any point in implementing it now. *However*, the project has not been deployed, and there will be changes every week to add to the existing code.

Are there any types of tests I can add to the site that I can run daily to ensure my code is always working?  In case other people starting development on the site, or any new code is added, or old code is edited?

Comment: Yes, you can add tests after the fact.  However, if your project was not written with test in mind, it will be much harder to test than it would have been otherwise.

Comment: Writing tests has a lot to do with how the application was built as a whole.  Applications with clear separation of concerns and multi-layered is going to be easier (and more effective) to write tests for than an application that has C-Sharp and SQL interspersed.  Testing your business layer is always a good start, as that should be the backbone of your application.

Answer (score 2):

Of course there are types of tests you can add:

- [Unit tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) - testing classes in isolation (assuming a DI structure to the code)
- [Integration tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) - testing interactions between classes (typically two classes)
- [UI tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools) - using automation (selenium for example, to automate the browser) to test the application from UI through to the database
- [Performance testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing)

It is best to concentrate on areas of change (bug fixes, feature requests) in order to get the best bang for the buck.

Nitpick: [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) is a design methodology using testing frameworks, not a testing methodology.

Answer (score 0):

If there will be weekly changes, "the project has had most of the development completed" is probably not a true statement.  Most of the development, in fact, still lies ahead.

It is still very worth introducing unit tests.  I would suggest creating new tests each week that cover the areas of code that undergo maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you wouldn't be implementing TDD if you are retro fitting tests into a legacy codebase.  I would suggest investing time in producing at least unit tests for new code.  Hopefully your code will encroach on legacy code which you can then place unit tests around.  Baby steps is the key with legacy code.  There is no hard and fast way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests can always be added, and it's always a good idea to add them. I would suggest NUnit in your case, because it seems to work really well with existing code. It's also really easy to use.